# How to exclude weekends and holidays in duration calculation on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

Here's my dataset, To make sure you know the data format, before that I did

```
df['Datetime_Start'] =  df['Start'].dt.strftime('%D')
df['Datetime_Finish'] =  df['Finish'].dt.strftime('%D')
```

The selected interesting columns

```
No  Datetime_Start    Datetime_Finish
1   13/08/18          31/08/18
1   14/08/18          25/08/18
```

The output I Expected

```
No  Datetime_Start    Datetime_Finish    Duration
1   13/08/18          31/08/18           12 Days
1   14/08/18          24/08/18           6 Days
```

This is because 18, 19, 25, and 26 August 2018 is Saturday and Sunday, and 17 and 22 is a Public Holiday (In Indonesia)

This the links of public holiday in Indonesia https://publicholidays.co.id/2018-dates/, but it is ok if you only include 17 and 22 August 2018 for answering the question, but please make this configurable, so I can add manually

Comment: Do you have an ical file with public holidays available somewhere?

Comment: what ical? I don't have any for today

Comment: Some online calendar that lists public holidays? There's nothing included in pandas that knows about holidays, so another source is needed.

Comment: This the links, https://publicholidays.co.id/2018-dates/, but it is ok if you only include 17 and 22 August 2018, but please make this configurable, so I can add manually

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be one way. The basic idea is that I expand the range to all dates in between (`pd.date_range`) and then use different criteria to filter the dates that should not be counted:

```
import pandas as pd

import requests

from icalendar import Calendar

ics_url = 'https://www.calendarlabs.com/ical-calendar/ics/50/Indonesia_Holidays.ics'

df = {'Datetime_Start': pd.to_datetime(['2018-08-13', '2018-08-14']),
      'Datetime_End': pd.to_datetime(['2018-08-31', '2018-08-25'])}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

df['days_in_range'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: pd.date_range(x['Datetime_Start'], x['Datetime_End']),
    axis=1)

# remove weekends
df['days_in_range'] = df['days_in_range'].apply(lambda x: x[x.dayofweek <= 4])

# remove holidays
calendar = Calendar.from_ical(requests.get(ics_url).content)
holidays = [pd.to_datetime(x['DTSTART'].dt).date()
            for x in calendar.walk('VEVENT')]

df['days_in_range'] = df['days_in_range'].apply(
    lambda x: [y for y in x if y.date() not in holidays])

df['Duration'] = df['days_in_range'].apply(lambda x: len(x) - 1)
```

There are definitely chances to speed this up and there are also some hidden assumptions:

- Ranges always consist of at least one countable day for the result. Corner cases are not handled.
- It is assumed that the ical file doesn't use recurrence.